# How does mitmproxy match requests for server-playback or how to tune mitmproxy request matches

Tags: mitmproxy

Need information on how mitmproxy matches requests for server playback

I have mitmproxy configured and working. I have captured flows and am trying to use server replay.  I can only get it to work by not matching the incoming requests.

The only way I can get it to work is if I use the '--set server_replay_ignore_content=true' option.  This seems to result in a sequential playback of server responses, which is fine sometimes, but timing differences will eventually lead to mismatched request-response playbacks.  I would like to know how the matching is being performed.  Is there any way to determine how mitmproxy has either matched a flow-request or why it has rejected a match?  What fields are being used for the match comparison?  I cannot find any specific information in the documentation.  Increasing the log verbosity did not help.  I have also tried using the 'server_replay_ignore_params' option, experimenting with various json message fields that might have caused problems (some of these vary between the same request-messages for our application, but most do not). It would have been nice if increased log verbosity (-vvv)  could have shown information that could helped me fine-tune the matches.  My python skills are novice level, so I am seeking information other than advice to trace the source code.

Comment: Mitmproxy is open source so you can check it yourself where the `server_replay_ignore_content` option is processed: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/ab9429e3f6f831290f2a104a25b084f3f25b6452/mitmproxy/addons/serverplayback.py#L158

Comment: A closer reading of the server replay section - "By default, we exclude request headers when matching incoming requests with responses from the replay file, and use only the URL and request method for matching. "

Comment: This documentation is vague however, since there is a 'server_replay_ignore_payload_params' option available.  The code referenced by Robert seems to show the hash key being extended by the payload parameters unless present in the argument to this option.  So the payload section is also being used for generating the match.  My case is multipart form section, and as stated in the original question, I have experimented with these fields to no effect.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The header fields ‘*scheme*’, ‘*method*’, and ‘*path*’ are hashed to form a lookup key.  That key is extended by each field in the payload section, unless they have been specified by *server_replay_ignore_payload_params*.

In my previous attempts to limit varying fields, I mistakenly used  *server_replay_ignore_params* which is applied to the header, not the payload section.